# Rails 3.1 Deploy to Production (with Apache & Passenger) Asset Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, production, assets

Rails 3.1 has changed the way it handles the asset pipeline and it is causing issues when deploying to production.

I am using Apache and Passenger, which seem to work fine.

My production is setup like this (for now).

```
# congif/environments/production.rb
config.cache_classes = false
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
```

I run rake assets:precompile on Ubuntu and start server.  And... nothing.  None of my images load.

The legendary 'I can't find an image at this URL' box.

I run rake assets:precompile on CentOS and start server.  And... permission errors.

```
*Error Compiling CSS Asset*
Errno::EACCESS: Permission Denied - [app path]/tmp/cache/assets/E95
[path to RVM Ruby]/fileutils.rb:243:in 'mkdir'
```

I can't get it to budge.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

### UPDATE

This solution has worked every time for me:

First Clean out your Assets

```
rm -rf public/assets
```

and

```
rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production
```

Second, in #production.rb change

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Third, run to precompile your assets

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Fourth, in #production.rb change

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

back to

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Fifth, restart your server by running:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Sixth, un-restrict permissions on your newly created assets by running this command

chmod -R 777 public/assets

Seventh, celebrate!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a simple permission problem. Give the server/daemon the right to create files in [app_path]/tmp recursively.

Assuming your server process runs with the `www-data` user you do this with:

```
cd APP_PATH
chmod -R u+w tmp
```

and if the directory does not belong to the user you have to change the ownership:

```
chown -R www-data tmp
```

Comment: I tried this and it is still fighting me with the same error.  I am on CentOS and www-data isn't the valid user.  I tried it the the apache user. Update:  I did chown -R 755 tmp and it worked!

Comment: Ok you fixed my CentOS error and Michael de Silva fixed my Ubuntu error.  Thanks guys!

Comment: how do I do this on Heroku? I have the same problems where an image is giving me the access-denied treatment

Comment: i made the changes locally and pushed it onto heroku. everything works fine now

Answer (score 4):

Try creating `public/assets` via sudo or try performing `rvmsudo rake assets:precompile` - essentially, it's not able to create the directory on your server — hence the error.

Comment: Ok you fixed my Ubuntu error and topek fixed my CentOS error. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8:

1. Remove references to stylesheets
2. Restart production
3. Go to an affected page using browser
4. Add stylesheet references back
5. Restart production
6. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your updated solution did not work for me.
I am on rails 4.2 and css and js works only when I set 
config.serve_static_files = true (which is not recommended but it is the only way I can make things work here).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This might be better posted as a comment.