# assets:precompile - permission denied - only on one computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, asset-pipeline, precompile

I have a rails app project folder which is on my dropbox folder.

I work on 2 computers - home pc and a laptop (both win 7)

If I do `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on the pc it works fine and I see the line

```
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe C:/Ruby193/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
mkdir -p H:/My Dropbox/project/public/assets
cp -r C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7.1/vendor/assets/javascripts/tinymce H:/My Dropbox/project/public/assets
```

but on the laptop I get persmission denied on one of the tinymce files and the precompilation fails..

the app folder has permissions for everyone.. 
Any ideas why this could happen?

Update:

It seems it stops on files randomly.. not necessarily tinymce.
I've set all ruby files and project file to have permissions to everyone (win 7) and set all that was read only to not be that.

this is very frustrating

an example of a --trace output. note that everytime I run assets:precompile it stops at a different file. this time it stopped on one of my icons

```
H:\My Dropbox\project>bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe C:/Ruby193/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Permission denied - H:/My Dropbox/project/public/assets/Icons/ArrowDown-335eb652931bdc13061ad1745a25556f.jpg
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/static_asset.rb:47:in `utime'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/static_asset.rb:47:in `write_to'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:41:in `block in write_asset'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:38:in `tap'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:38:in `write_asset'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:24:in `block in compile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe C:/Ruby193/bin/rak...]
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Some things to try: 1. Make sure permissions [are set recursively](http://serverfault.com/questions/157461/set-permissions-recursively-on-windows-7) on the Dropbox folder. 2. [Clean it all out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920298/rails-3-1-deploy-to-production-with-apache-passenger-asset-problems) and try again. 3. Does not sound like a sync issue but if dropbox folder is mounted on NTFS - try [mounting it with you as user](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=18517#post-168122). Does using the `--trace` flag in the `rake` command provide any more information?

Comment: Moral of the story: don't develop with Ruby on Windows. This is one of a long line of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Start by eliminating possible problems.

First, remove DropBox from the equation. Check out and compile on a local hard drive.

Second, make sure TinyMCE is in your Gemfile and installed with bundler. Your project shouldn't be pulling gems from the global gems but project specific, bundled gems.

If that fails, you'll need to follow Digital Cake's advice and provide us with a --trace output.

Comment: the dropbox is on a local hard drive. I try to complie when no other computer is working, and no one else accesses that folder. It seems that not only TinyMCE is making that trouble.. I've add the trace

Comment: I'm still suspicious of the "My Dropbox" folder. Can you try compiling from somewhere on your C:\ drive?  The error could mean a number of things, no space, some hard drive problem making the bits unwritable, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but I would think that the permission is because of a tmp fold used to temporarily store the files as they are pre compiled. a --trace should give you better error logs and that would be key to figuring out where the error is happening.